# tess4j under windows 10

Tags: java, windows, tesseract

I can't get tess4j to work under Windows 10.

http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ states:

> Tesseract, Leptonica, and Ghostscript Windows 32- and 64-bit DLLs are
>   embedded in tess4j.jar; they will automatically be extracted and
>   loaded at run-time.

Indeed it tries to, but it seems to be optimized for windows versions prior to 10. I needed to give rights to all kinds of directories, but now it says 
(Toegang geweigerd = "Access denied")

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to create  temporary file
for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll library: Toegang geweigerd
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:776)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:78)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:40)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:360)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:273)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:256)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:237)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:221)
at LPokerbot.LPokerbot.Card.ocrChar(Card.java:42)
at LPokerbot.LPokerbot.Card.recognize(Card.java:37)
at LPokerbot.LPokerbot.App.start(App.java:38)
at LPokerbot.LPokerbot.App.main(App.java:27)
```

I have no clue what the tmp dir may be. I've tried to create some dirs in C:\temp, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it solved. In the VM properties, set

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp -DTESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Users\user\workspace\LPokerbot\src\main\resources\
```

C:\Temp will be created and it will work. Originally, java.io.tmpdir would be C:\WINDOWS and of course it doesn't have rights there. The second -D sets the path of eng.traineddata file This is kindof offtopic but you'll run into the following error.

```
Error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

You need to download that file, and in my case it's placed in

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\LPokerbot\src\main\resources\tessdata\
```

In your code, retrieve the property and set it:

```
tesseract.setDatapath(System.getProperty("TESSDATA_PREFIX"));
```

For some reason, setting the evironment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX doesn't work.

Comment: The tmpdir normally is `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Temp`, but it may be different on yours.